# splicing an element IN a JSON list- javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, splice, stringify

I have the following line being printed on my screen:

```
Would you like to pay €xx to POS_ID Latte  X 1....€2.50-Salad  X 1....€4.00-Wrap  X 1....€4.50-Coffee X 2....€3.00-
```

What I want is for it to look like this:

```
Would you like to pay €xx to POS_ID
"Latte  X 1....€2.50-
Salad  X 1....€4.00-
Wrap  X 1....€4.50-
Coffee X 2....€3.00-".
```

I am creating this message by parsing the following JSON:

```
{"action":"POS_clear","id":"POS_ID","paramater":"14.00", "purchaseList":"Latte  X 1....€2.50-Salad  X 1....€4.00-Wrap  X 1....€4.50-Coffee X 2....€3.00-", "ClientID":"1234"}
```

What I had done originally was used /n instead of - but then I ran into trouble parsing the JSON (because of the /) so I swapped the slash for a dash and thought I could splice it somehow? But I'm a bit lost. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Since they are showing up in HTML page, try replacing the dashes with html tag `<br>`.

Comment: literally just thought of that a minute before seeing this! Thanks :)